# Managed properties missing in the search results webpart when not using the querystring

Tags: search, managed-property, display-template, content-search-web-part

When using the search results webpart without the querystring (For instance when trying to use managed metadata navigation) I am unable to view custom managed properties AND am unable to see any hitsummary information.

For the example below, te webpart is configured with the query value directly inserted in it's query parameter under webpart properties. No other modifications were done.

In the following pictures, you can see the exact same query twice with the exact same result. Only without using the querystring the hitsummary information is missing. With the querystring my result is fine.

With querystring:

[image]

Without querystring:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you pass a blank querystring? As in ?k=

Comment: What is the question here please? how-to? why? anything else?

Comment: What do I need to explain?

Comment: @F.Aquino Sorry I wasn't able to test this

Answer (score 2):

I just left my client and was unable to resolve this error.

The only thing I could do to fix it was basically create a completely new custom display template and recover the hoverpanel and WAC preview window functionality. With my own display template everything worked perfectly fine as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a k parameter in any case, in SP2013 you can put:
?k=*
as "all documents filter"